# Git commit locally not working, stalling and hanging to blinking cursor in bash

Tags: git, git-commit

All of a sudden this morning, I can't seem to commit to git.  When I run:

```
git commit -m 'replacing location.origin with location.host as former isn't supported in ie8'
```

It never seems to execute, I'm left in my git bash with:

```
> _
```

Where the underscore blinks.

I was able to run a git status and git add fine, I just can't seem to commit, where I've never had this problem before.  Anyone have any ideas what's going on and how I can fix this?

I've restarted my PC (I do this first thing every Monday am).

I also tried running a git gc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used a ' in your log message, which ends the string quotation.

Do not use -m, or escape the ' like '\'' or put the whole thing in "…" instead or use typographic question marks ’ inside the commit message instead of the ASCII apostrophe.

Comment: I've always used -m and single quotes for my messages.  That's how gitref.org has it:  git commit -m 'changes to hello file'  What am I missing?

Comment: OMG, nevermind, I see the ' in don't...Holy cow, I can\'t believe I missed that :)  My god, what a retard I am.

Comment: That “isn't” contains a single quote, which terminates your message. You need to quote the quote ☺